# How to use json_decode a post_meta value?

Tags: array, post-meta, json

I have used `get_post_meta($post->ID)` to get all custom fields for my post since I have many of htem. Some of them were checkbox values and `var_dumping` the variable gives me this

```
array (size=1) 0 => string 'a:3:{i:0;s:6:"ozujak";i:1;s:7:"travanj";i:2;s:7:"svibanj";}
```

How do I echo those values?

I have tried  `var_dump(json_decode($meta['my_var']));` but it gives me `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values look like they have been serialized using [`maybe_serialize( $data )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize).

If that's the case, then you can reverse that with [`maybe_unserialize( $original )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize).

As per this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18465/84219), [`unserialize( $str )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) will also create a PHP value from a stored representation.

---

Try:

```
$mydata = 'a:3:{i:0;s:6:"ozujak";i:1;s:7:"travanj";i:2;s:7:"svibanj";}';

$mydata = unserialize($mydata);

echo $mydata[0]; // ozujak
```

Comment: The `maybe` is used in cases where you aren't quite sure. Because you know, unserialized will eventually be called.