# how to add custom user capabilities using add_user_meta or something else?

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, capabilities, user-access

i have two WordPress sites with SSO Configurations as described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/single-sign-on-between-two-wordpress-website) but the plugin in the answer didn't work for me so i tried to write a code to add capabilities for second site users:

```
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'author'));
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        add_user_meta( $user->id, 'orewpst_capabilities', "a:1:{s:6:'author';b:1;}", true ); 
        add_user_meta( $user->id, 'orewpst_user_level', '2', true ); 
    }
}
```

the problem is the output result for `"a:1:{s:6:'author';b:1;}"` is `s:23:"a:1:{s:6:'author';b:1;}"`

i don't know what "s:23" means and why it appears in database!

**update**: I want the string `"a:1:{s:6:'author';b:1;}"` to store in database with out any change! but somehow my code adds an "s:23:" before it.

Comment: i found this solution on the web witch is working but somehow my website loading page slows down a bit. https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/how-to-extract-data-from-a-post-meta-serialized-array

Comment: @admcfajn that wasn't the solution as i don't want the string to be an array. converting it to an array (unserialize) wouldn't do any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the value without serializing it manually, because WordPress will do it for you anyway:

```
add_user_meta( $user->id, 'orewpst_capabilities', array( 'author' => 1 ), true );
```

or

```
update_user_meta( $user->id, 'orewpst_capabilities', array( 'author' => 1 ) ); // it will create the meta data for you if it doesn't exist already.
```

The `s:23` means that you stored a string with 23 chars.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

That's right the `s:23` is serialized data. WordPress automatically store the data in serialized format.

Also, To set the user capabilities use function `add_cap()` instead of updating the user meta. For more details check WordPress handbook [user roles and capabilities](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/).